# English dictionary library in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, libraries

I need a library in Python 3 to define terms (vocabulary words), building a English dictionary. Input a term and the output will be the definition of this term.

Comment: On most Unix systems, there is an existing list of English words at `/usr/share/dict/words`.

Comment: hmm... Linux not found "dict folder".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried PyDictionary?

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

dictionary=PyDictionary("dog","cat","tree")
print(dictionary.printMeanings()) #This prints the definitions
```

https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/